# How to set rewrite in iis to rewrite my url

Tags: windows-8, iis-8

now i need to complete a new feature, i have two url address. For example, first is http://a.com/, second is http://b.com. but for some reasons, i can't use any codes of first. so i need to add a redirect in iis of first. i use the rewrite to help me do that. but i tried, all are failed.
**for example, when iis got a request like "http://a.com/a1/a2", it will jump to http://b.com/a1/a2.now i don't know how to write the condition.**

anybody can help me? thanks very much.
please ignore some grammatical errors.very appreciate

Comment: Read up on using IIS "host headers" too as it may be of some use here but not 100% certain but would be worth a read and simple enough to test too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up such condition normally with two sites. On with binding to b.com. Then I add a second site with binding to a.com. Then you can go to the **HTTP Redirect** section in IISadmin an add your redirect. Per default, the redirect uses your parameters.

Is there any reason to use **URL rewrite**?

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
To be exact, i am not very understand iis. i just know rewrite can help me do that, but now it's not easy for me. maybe i can try to use HTTP Redirect.

Comment: **HTTP Redirect** is very useful. I solved my question.  Many thanks! very appreciate!

Comment: but i got a new question. for example, redirect url is http://a$S?r=apac. r=apac is necessary for me. but when an old url like http://a?dc=d0001, after redirect, the new url is http://a?r=apac. but what i wanted is http://a?dc=d0001&r=apac. what should i do? any suggestion?

Comment: You can use the parameters:
https://msftplayground.com/2011/01/http-redirect-with-query-string-in-iis-7/
and here you find the documentation for those parameters:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525695(v%3Dvs.90). 

Pay attention to use **exact destination** in combination with parameters. Then you should find a solution.

Comment: I gave up this way. Because the string what i added is not fixed. If the old url include a "?", i need to add "&r=apac", otherwise i need to add "?r=apac". so i don't think they can work well. now i do these things in my code. just 3 lines code. it's more easy. whatever,  very appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The URL Rewrite extension for IIS is available for download from
[Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337).

You would find more information and downloads in the iis.net article of
[URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Comment: Oh God, i don't think i can read this article without google translate.

Comment: Much documentation is available from the above first link : Expand "Related resources" to see.

Comment: it's working now. maybe i should restart iis after i change something.